# Better CSS Inspector than Chrome Developer Tools for Mobile

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I am a windows user and sometimes, the mobile styles that show in Chrome Developer tools are not the same as what actually shows in, for example, an iPhone. Is there a more accurate way to debug CSS on a mobile device other than Chrome DevTools?

Comment: From safari, you can debug a webpage directly on an iPhone if it is plugged in (might require a Mac - not sure if this is available for Safari on Windows). Here's how: http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: ^ the goal is to be able to simulate from your computer without actually having an iphone

Comment: I suppose - I just wanted to make it known that it was an option. Anytime I've had issues with CSS displaying on my phone, the quickest way to solve it is to plug it into my mac and debug it from the phone directly.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was a Windows users. I don't have a Mac.